# Adding users one after another in JMeter

Tags: jmeter, load

I need to perform the following scenario in JMeter:

Every 20 seconds a user will start pinging the server (will ping every 5 seconds)
1000 users.

So it start with one user that will ping every 5 seconds and after 20 sec another user will start pinging every 5 sec, and this will continue for 1000 users.

At the end 1000 users will ping together every 5 sec and all this need to run for 24 hours.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define Thread Group with 1000 users,

Ramp Up Period 20000 - meaning every 20 seconds new users will start

Loop Count = 17280 (5 seconds per day count)

and add as a child to your ping request a [Constant Timer](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Constant_Timer) with 5000 milliseconds

It will execute every 20 seconds a new user which will ping every 5 seconds. example in View Results Tree:
[image]

Comment: how did you get to loop count = 17280? what is the math behind?

Comment: @Limbo 60 Seconds * 60 minutes * 24 hours / 5 seconds